# Updating salary on employees for each full year they have been working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to do what i say in the title. I have to update the salary on employees for each full year they have been working. I'm using the HR schema, so you can try it. The code I have right now is like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_salary (v_employee_id number) 
RETURN number IS v_result  number;

BEGIN
UPDATE employees SET salary =
        CASE
            WHEN sysdate-hire_date >=1 THEN salary +(salary*0.01)
            ELSE salary
        END
    INTO v_result WHERE employee_id = v_employee_id;

RETURN v_result;

END new_salary;
/
```

This code isn's working yet, what more should I do? Also, I don't know how to say that the salary must multiply more times. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I'm using the HR schema, so you can try it."  No, you need to edit your questions and post example sample data and expected output.  thanks.

Comment: You might want to try adding a COMMIT statement. Also - `SYSDATE - HIRE_DATE` produces a number of days, not number of years. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INTO` can not be used with the `UPDATE` statement.

You can use the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEW_SALARY (
    V_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER IS
    V_RESULT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, HIRE_DATE) / 12 >= 1 
            THEN SALARY + ( SALARY * 0.01 )
                 -- SALARY + ( SALARY * 0.01 * TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, HIRE_DATE)/12))
                 -- CODE TO MULTIPLY THE INCREMENT WITH NUMBER OF YEARS.
            ELSE SALARY
        END
    INTO V_RESULT
    FROM
        EMPLOYEES
    WHERE
        EMPLOYEE_ID = V_EMPLOYEE_ID;

    UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET
        SALARY = V_RESULT
    WHERE
        EMPLOYEE_ID = V_EMPLOYEE_ID;

    COMMIT;
    RETURN V_RESULT;
END NEW_SALARY;
/
```

Cheers!!